# Excel Color Change When Using Slicer

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors, excel-2010

I have problem using excel color chart. First of all I'm using color theme that I already set before.
lets say
A: Blue
B: Purple
C: Orange
D: Green

[image]

but after I'm using slicer which not include the B: purple
the color that I set before become

A: Blue
C: Purple
D: Orange

Can I somehow event using slicer still got the same color I set before?
I mean like this

A: Blue
C: Orange
D: Green

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Whether bug or feature is up to the beholder.

There's an article on Jon Peltier's blog, written by Jon Acampora, [Pivot Chart Formatting Changes when Filtered](https://peltiertech.com/pivot-chart-formatting-changes/), discussing the problem and possible workarounds. Check it out. It has a sample file to download and play around with. The essence is:

> Simple Workarounds One way to prevent the formatting from changing is
> to create a regular chart that references the PivotTable data.  With
> either of the following solutions we want to avoid the PivotChart all
> together, and instead create a regular chart.  Again, the regular
> charts do NOT suffer from the formatting issues when filters are
> applied.
>
> Solution #1 This can be accomplished by applying the technique in
> Jon’s article Making Regular Charts from PivotTables.  With that
> technique you basically create a regular chart and then carefully add
> the data series to the chart by referencing areas within the
> PivotTable.  You just have to be careful with the areas you select or
> reference because Excel has a tendency to want to convert the regular
> chart to a PivotChart.
>
> Solution #2 The other option is to create a new area on the worksheet
> that contains a replica of the PivotTable.  This area just contains
> formulas that reference the PivotTable.  You can either use the direct
> cell references like (=C9) or the GETPIVOTDATA() function to point to
> the PivotTable.  You might want to use the GETPIVOTDATA function if
> you only want to display a subset of your PivotTable data in the
> chart.
>
> The advantage of this technique is that once you have the formula
> based PivotTable setup, you can reference the entire area of the
> source data range to quickly create a chart that includes all your
> series.  It might save you time over having to add the series
> individually as you do in solution #1.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: hi @teylyn, it's different case I guess, because I have a lot of slicer with connect to the A, B, C, and D. So everytime I'm trying to slice the other the color is not sync

Comment: Why is that a different case? The colours change when you change the slicer/filter. Have you tried the solution? Use a regular chart, then you have much more control over the colours. You can use formulas to determine how to populate the worksheet grid that serves as the chart data source..

Answer (score 0):

Slicer filters the data, so Excel only sees the filtered results and applies the colour mapping to them without knowing how many results it skips, hence the strange colouring system.

One solution (but it doesn't use a slicer) is to set the data value of a pie slice to zero. This way the data is still rendered, but as a zero-width slice, and the colour count increases as normal.